# validating HTML

Tags: html, w3c-validation

I am beginner in HTML and CSS. I just designed web site and tried to validate but my HTML end up having some "geovisit();"
 and it wont validate.
I do not know how to get rid of it. 
Help me?
Thank you 
Guest

Comment: We will need more information. Edit the question, add which validator you are using, the error it is giving and copy the HTML that is not validating. Make sure you format correctly too ;)

Answer (score 7):

A quick [Google search for geovisit](http://www.google.com/search?q=geovisit) suggests that the non-validating code is being added by your hosting provider. It looks like this problem may actually be specific to Yahoo!, which has an option to disable that "feature". I suggest you read [this forum thread on the problem](http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t162467-yahoo-server-generated-code-wont-validate.html).

Answer (score 1):

That's usually Yahoo (or other hosting providers) sticking javascript on your page without your knowing. In Yahoo's case you should be able to turn it off if you dig through the settings.